# arangoimp closed immediately and query result

Tags: arangodb, arangoimport

I'm using the latest ArangoDB of the respective release series: 3.1

Mode: Single-Server

On this operating system: Windows, version: 10

My problem is: when I open `arangoimp.exe` file, it asks me to enter a password, when it is entered and I press (Enter) it will automatically be closed... So what is the solution?

My another question is: can I have the result of the AQL query by graph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered on [github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4960) arangoimp is meant to be invoked in an interactive shell (like cmd, bash or powershell).

After executing an AQL query at the web UI it is possible to display the result as JSON or Graph (top right at the result box), download the result as JSON or open the result in the Graph Viewer.